# Kendo fail to get json file and parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, kendo-ui

I have below JSON file stored on remote server `server\test.json`:

```
{
    "ABC1": [
        {
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value"
        },
        {
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value"
        }
    ],
    "ABC2": {
        "field": "value",
        "field": "value"
    },
    "ABC3": [
        {
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value",
            "XYZ1": {
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value"
            },
            "field": "value"
        },
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get this json file and render it's contains using Kendo + AngularJS.
I have tried below method to get the file:

```
this.detailsData = new kendo.data.DataSource(
{
schema: {

   // How to define schema for this json?    
},

transport: 
{
    read: 
    {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "server/test.json"
    }
},
change: function (data) 
{
    alert("Success :"+data);
},
error: function (xhr, error) 
{
    alert("Error");
    console.debug(xhr);
    console.debug(error);
}
});
```

I am not able to get the file, every time I get the error "alert".
And in browser debug logs, I get error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" and  status: "parsererror".
I am calling `this.detailsData.read();` on some events.

I am able to access this file from browser with out any issue.

what is wrong with this code?
And also how to define schema for this json?

Comment: As far as i know `kendo.dataSource` accept only arrays.

Comment: So is it that it will not be possible to process this json using kendo? also is their any other way to display this json in using Kendo?

Comment: What kendo control are you using to display data?

Comment: I am not using anything right now everything is currently in backed for now. just added one dummy `kendo-mobile-conten` and `kendo-mobile-view`. Finally I want to display sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you intentionally trying to retrieve jsonp data?  This is different than json.  If you're not expecting jsonp, then change your datatype declaration to simple json:

```
dataType: "json",
```

As far as defining your datasource schema, if you can manipulate the JSON data format coming from the server, try giving it a main object name (myData in the case below).

```
 {
    myData: [{
        "ABC1": [
            {
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value"
            },
            {
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value",
                "field": "value"
            }
        ],
        "ABC2": {
            "field": "value",
            "field": "value"
        },
        "ABC3": [
                    {
                        "field": "value",
                        "field": "value",
                        "field": "value",
                        "XYZ1": {
                            "field": "value",
                            "field": "value",
                            "field": "value"
                        },
                        "field": "value"
                    },
                ]
            }]
    }
```

Then all you have to do to define the schema in your kendo datasource is reference this object name:

```
schema: {
            data: 'myData'
        }
```

Comment: I can not modify json data received form server and add root variable object to it, and also I don't know if it is possible to do it.